# logging.getLogger('name').setLevel() does not seem to work

Tags: python, logging

I have here my example code trying to set a default logger level to info, and although the object says it's level is info, I still get nothing from logger.info()

Running python3.6:

```
import logging
a = logging.getLogger('a')
a.info('bla') # should be ignored as a's level is warning
a.warning('bla')
a.setLevel('INFO')
a.info('bla') # should now work, but still nothing is shown...
```

Running from iPython:

```
In [1]: import logging 
   ...: a = logging.getLogger('a') 
   ...: a                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[1]: <Logger a (WARNING)>
In [2]: a.info('bla') # should be ignored as a's level is warning                                                                                                                            
In [3]: a.warning('bla')                                                                                                                                                                     
bla
In [4]: a.setLevel('INFO')                                                                                                                                                                   
# nothing
In [5]: a                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[5]: <Logger a (INFO)>
In [6]: a.info('bla') # should now work, but still nothing is shown...                                                                                                                       
# **still nothing...**
```

Comment: The output is managed by a *handler*, not the logger. Try e.g. `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` to set the default handler's log level. Otherwise you're using https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.lastResort

Comment: Your log doesn't have a console handler so the log is propagated to another level. Just add a console handler and disable the propagation.